# $.getJSON works on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, azure, getjson

When I go to `localhost` on my Arch Linux machine, which has Apache installed, the following code successfully loads the JSON file.

```
$.getJSON("geo/my.json",function(jsonStuff){
  // Code here
})
```

But when I navigate to my Microsoft Azure-powered server, my web browser's console displays this message.

`GET https://path/to/my.json 404 (Not Found)`

I know the files and folders are there because I transferred them to the remote server through FileZilla. When I use FileZilla to open the folder containing `my.json`, I see the file there.

The root directory looks like this.

```
index.html
geo
  my.json
js
  script.js
```

When I navigate my browser to `https://path/to/my.json`, I see this message.

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`.

Why won't `$.getJSON` work on my remote server?

Comment: Do you have your root directory for your site set correctly in Apache? If you go to `https://yoursite.com/` does that open your index.html file?
Will usually look like `DocumentRoot /var/www/yoursite/htdocs`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your document root is set correctly in your website's Apache configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

            ServerAdmin admin@yoursite.com
            ServerName yoursite.com
            ServerAlias www.yoursite.com
            DocumentRoot /path/to/your/website/directory     <-Make sure this is correct.
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
            SSLEngine on

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

If your `my.json` file is located at `/var/www/mysite/geo/my.json` then your DocumentRoot should be `DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite`. Hope that helps.